# Magento 2 exclude specific product discount from category

Tags: magento, magento2

I have categories that I have applied a price cart rule with coupon code that makes an discount on the products added to cart. But now I would like to exclude some products of specific category.

For example I have category: 1, 2, 3 and 4 with applied discount, so when a user add products from these categories to cart for example: product1, product2, product3 and product4 from "Category 1" and apply the coupon code he will have a discount on these products.

Where products cost: product1 - 10 usd; product2 - 10 usd; product3 - 10 usd; product 4 - 10 usd;

A total of 40 usd and if the coupon code with 10% discount is used he will have to pay 36 usd (4 usd discount)

---

But now am I trying to make an exclude of products to not apply discount as follow the example: user again add to his cart product1, product2, product3 and product4 but this time product3 and product4 will not be discounted, so he will get a discount only for product1 and product2.

Where products cost: product1 - 10 usd; product2 - 10 usd; product3 - 10 usd; product 4 - 10 usd;

A total of 40 usd and if the coupon code with 10% discount is used he wil have to pay 38 usd (2 usd discount as he is getting discount only for product1 and product2)

How should I configure the rule in Conditions and Action Tab to achive this goal and what is the right way to do it?